# How to close sessions on Postgresql with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlmodel

In this configuration

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine, async_sessionmaker

db_engine = create_async_engine('<DATABASE_URL>', echo=False, future=True)
async_session = async_sessionmaker(db_engine, class_=AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)


async def get_session() -> AsyncSession:
    async with async_session() as session:
        yield session
        await session.close()
```

I can connect to the Postgresql DB, but by some several connections stay open. Is that an issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation on [connection pooling](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html)?

Comment: @GordThompson Many thanks for getting back to me. However, what I do not understand is why the connections are not closed despite I explicitly use `session.close()`.

Comment: "a connection pool is the standard way to maintain a 'pool' of active database connections in memory which are reused across requests" - so when the application "closes" its connection the underlying driver (DBAPI) connection is simply returned to the pool for re-use.

Comment: Exactly, but wouldn't that mean that I do not see any open connections that simply stay (!) open?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a connection pool to get a session, `SQLAlchemy` will keep some connections open so that you can reuse them without waiting for a new connection to be established.

By default this number is `5`, but you can change it by passing `pool_size` parameter to `async_sessionmaker`.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html

BTW, you don't have to call `session.close()` since you are using context manager and it will do it for you when you exit from `with`